# how to not loop for every value Info in MainvalueInfo

Tags: python

I have some logic with two for loops as below ,I dont want the "for value in valueInfo['valueInfo']" to be repeated for every valueInfo in MainvalueInfo,
FYI MainvalueInfo looks like below,I only want to run "for valueInfo in MainvalueInfo" only once to get the valueInfo and the "for value in valueInfo['valueInfo']"
should be repeated for every value..can anyone suggest how can this be done?

```
MainvalueInfo = {'Assignee': 'username', 'RCAInfo': 'Provided', 'PLProductLine': 'LNX.LA.0.0', 'valueInfo': [{'Url': 'https://review-android.company.com/761190', 'Status': 'MERGED', 'kw_ran': 'kw running', 'Info': 'ALREADY INTEGRATED', 'lookahead_ran': 'lookahead running'}, {'Url': 'https://review-android.company.com/777849', 'Status': 'NEW', 'kw_ran': 'kw did not run', 'Info': 'Available', 'lookahead_ran': 'lookahead running'}], 'CRId': '<a href="http://prism/CR/664310">664310</a>', 'CRStatus': 'Fix', 'RNotesStatus': 'Yes', 'TargetName': 'MSM8916', 'IsDevComplete': 'True'}

  for valueInfo in MainvalueInfo: #I dont want the below block to be repeated for every value in MainvalueInfo
    for value in valueInfo['valueInfo']:
       ................
```

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ - i am creating a table based on MainvalueInfo  info..now because of multiple entries in valueInfo there are duplicate entries,so I need for valueInfo in MainvalueInfo to be only once for valueInfo

Comment: try below answer. ur loop only runs once when the key is valueinfo

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in MainvalueInfo:
    if key =='valueInfo':
        for value in MainvalueInfo[key]
    else:pass

i think ur confused by naming conviction . try this .u understand better
run directly

for value in MainvalueInfo['valueInfo']:
```

dont loop the mainvalueinfo then

Comment: how does this help not to loop on the dictionary?

Comment: @user3654069 do u need to loop only mainvalueinfo['valueinfo']

Comment: yes,need to loop only on mainvalueinfo['valueinfo']

Comment: @user3654069 the directly use mainvalueinfo['valueinfo'] . what is problem in there